# Where do these namings in common lisp come from?

Tags: common-lisp

in common lisp, the names *labels* and *flet* are somewhat peculiar to me.

*flet* could be described as a sort of *let* for *f*unctions. So it named as such. What about *labels*?

And where does the "f" of *getf*, *setf*, *remf* come from?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

LABEL (without the s) is a very old (from the early Lisp dialect) construct that allows to give a name to a function so that it can call itself using that name:

Something like (this is not valid Common Lisp):

```
(label 'ff (lambda (x) (if (foo) (bar) (ff (baz)))))
```

It *label*s a function with a name.

For Common Lisp this name has been recycled. LABELS now allows to define local functions that can call themselves by name.

Answer (score 1):

Get form, set form, remove form.